# Not getting the desired FFT for sigma-delta modulator

Tags: matlab, fft, simulink, dft, adc

I have a second order sigma delta modulator in *simulink matlab*. it's working fine i applied a sinusoidal waveform to the input with `Vp - p = 1V` and i have the same waveform(with a little delay), after low-pass filtering in the output :

I get this for `fft` :
[fft](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycD26.jpg)

```
sampling freq=256 MHz
input freq= 4MHz
```

Period of sample and hold clock is `1/256MHZ`
And also sample time for `adc_out` block seen in the pic is `1/256MHz`
And i didn't touch anything else.

And i calculated the input freq based on this formula :

```
fin=(prime/N)* sampling freq
```

Prime is prime number, i chose `257`
`N` is number of fft points, i chose `16384`
sampling freq is `256MHz`
therefore i got 4MHz as the best input freq and these considerations, after fft, were supposed to give me a nice impulse at 4MHz and the shaped noise in the higher frequencies
as you can see i don't have my desired imupulse at 4MHz!
and i just don't know why!!

Answer (score 2):

Just peeking at the image, I'd say it's a [windowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function) issue. In particular, since you don't use an explicit window, you are using a block function. The FFT of a block is `sin(x)/x`, which is convoluted with your real response.

Comment: Yes, most probably that's the issue. But how to solve it? what i have done seems correct to me because based on the theory of sigma-delta modulator the noise level is shaped to higher frequencies and is the lowest at 4MHz but the signal tone is missing there! @MSalters

Comment: @Fateme: Pretty much any window function should help. Multiply `x` by that window before calling `fft(x)`.

Comment: I applied a hann window which i suppose is best for sigma-delta modulator types and yet i do not have my tone! the code: clc, close all
x=adc_out;
w=hann(16385,'periodic');
x=x.*w;
f=(abs(fft(x)))/16384;
dbpsd=20*log10(f);
freq=256*linspace(0,0.5,16384/2);
plot(freq,dbpsd(1:1:16384/2))

Comment: @Fateme: Sorry to hear, but that might be a decent new question (with before&after graphs)